# build.gradle does not recognize Closure

Tags: intellij-idea, build.gradle

I'm using Intellij 2021.1.2
JDK 1.8

I am built a project trying to follow http://scratchpad.pietschy.com/gradle/multi_project_builds.html

It shows where to find the source code, but I cannot find it.

Anyways, Gradle cannot find "Closure" and I see this in intelliJ:

[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KC14S.png)

Has anyone seen this issue? I'm not finding much help online.

Comment: Is it possible to share your sample project?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I was able to solve by creating the project over from scratch.